# How do you make the nushell prompt text not wrap?

Tags: shell, nushell

I have just started experimenting with NuShell, and I am wondering how to fix this issue. With my `prompt` config set as

```
prompt = "build-string (ansi y) (date format '%I:%M:%S') (ansi reset) ' ' (ansi g) (whoami) '@' (hostname) (ansi reset) ' ' (ansi r) (pwd) (ansi reset) ' '"
```

I am getting this prompt:

```
04:50:57 carl
@hp-pavilion
 /home/carl
```

How can I force the text to stay on one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It look like you need to strip the trailing newline from the output of `whom` and `hostname` yourself. I don't know if this is the *best* solution (never heard of NuShell until I saw this question), but this appears to work:

```
(whoami | str trim)
```